# TimePicker without the TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I want to use only the chooser dialog (shown below)

[image]

from the TimePicker control included in the Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone. Normally this dialog only appears when a user clicks on the TimePicker control listbox.

[image]

I would like to bypass the listbox altogether and launch the chooser dialog when a button is pressed.

Is this possible or would I have to create a custom control for myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create class that inherited from `TimePicker`, and use `ClickTemplateButton()` to simulate click behavior:

```
public class CustomPicker : TimePicker
{
    public void ClickTemplateButton()
    {
        Button button = (GetTemplateChild("DateTimeButton") as Button);
        ButtonAutomationPeer peer = new ButtonAutomationPeer(button);
        IInvokeProvider provider = (peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke) as IInvokeProvider);

        provider.Invoke();
    } 
}
```

When this class is created, create `CustomPicker` in xaml. Don't forget to add xmlns

```
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomPickerNamespace"


 <local:CustomPicker x:Name="customPicker" .../>
```

And then call you can show it from code:

```
 customPicker.ClickTemplateButton()
```

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I don't understand what you're trying to say. Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: Just in case this helps others, the code above didn't work for me until I added a call to `UpdateLayout()` at the start of the `ClickTemplateButton` method. Before doing so, `GetTemplateChild` just kept returning `null` for me.